# Checking whether a number is smaller or greater without using an array

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, compare, scanf

I am trying to check whether a number is greater or smaller in a `while` loop without using an array. I am trying to do it with the `scanf()` function, but have been unsuccesful so far.

I tried storing the initial value of the first number into a variable and then checking it at the next iteration of the loop, but I just don't know how. Any advice that helps me move with the code is appreciated greatly.

```
int number, nextNumber;

 while (...) {
        
        scanf("%d", &number)
        
        nextNumber = number;

        if (number >= nextNumber) {
            printf(...);

        }
```

Comment: Assign it with `nextNumber = number;` *after* making the comparison (at the end of the loop) - so it is really `lastNumber`. Initialise it before the loop begins.

Comment: "greater or smaller" than *what* ? I advise you explain the code you have [to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), because `nextNumber = number;` immediately following the read, followed by  `if (number >= nextNumber)` ? Did you *ever* expect that if-condition to be *false*, and if so, *how* ??

Comment: Greater or smaller than the next number being entered by the user in the next iteration of the loop. I basically want to ignore the first if iteration, since we don't know what the next number is yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number, nextNumber = INT_MIN;

while (...) {
        
    if(scanf("%d", &number) == 1)
        if (number > nextNumber) {
            nextNumber = number;
            /* ... */
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example that suggests the entries are correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int result;
    scanf("%d", &result);
    
    int number;
    while(scanf("%d", &number)==1) // Type a character when you're done.
    {
        if (number > result) result=number;
    }

    printf("The largest number is: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```